# psql foreign key and join tables by it

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, pgadmin

I have 3 tables:

```
pet:
id | ...

vaccination:
id | petId | ...

visit:
id | petId | ...
```

in `vaccination` and `visit` tables `petId` are foreign keys.

when I'm trying to make `join` I have error

```
select 
COALESCE(visit.petId, vaccination.petId) as petId,
GREATEST(visit.date, vaccination.date) as date
from visit
FULL JOIN vaccination on vaccination.petId = visit.petId
```

Or

```
(select petId from vaccination)
union all
(select petId from visit)
```

Error is:

```
column "petid" doesn't exist
Hint: Possibly a column reference was intended on "vaccination.petId"
```

I understand thet it is some kind of 'virtual' column generated by foreign key.
But I don't know how can I join it.
Thanks for help!
P.S. this tables were generated by typeorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column, scheme and table names are case sensitive, and when you don't have quote marks, PostgreSQL uses the lower case version of what you typed.

So use "petId", visit."petId" and vaccination."petId" to prevent unexpected lowercasing.

You can even decide to always have column, scheme and table names in quote marks, then you won't get caught out by this.   For example "vaccination"."petId"

Comment: oh. I've tryed in lower case but not in quotes. And the hint mess me.
It works! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the hint should mention case